# Cannot import `getReactNativePersistence` in `firebase@10.1.0`

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, react-native

I cannot import the `getReactNativePersistence` module from the `firebase/auth`. I'm using Typescript.

Importing the function as below was possible, but it didn't work when I updated the Firebase SDK from `9.22.0` to `10.1.0`.

```js
import { getReactNativePersistence } from "firebase/auth/react-native";
```

It seems like **there is no `firebase/auth/react-native` anymore.**

I also tried the following code, as [the document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth) indicates,

```js
import { getReactNativePersistence } from "firebase/auth";
```

But it throws an error.

```bash
Module '"firebase/auth"' has no exported member 'getReactNativePersistence'.
```

I'm using Expo, which uses Metro as default.

This is my `metro.config.js`

```js
// Learn more https://docs.expo.io/guides/customizing-metro
const { getDefaultConfig } = require('expo/metro-config');

module.exports = getDefaultConfig(__dirname);
```

How can I import `getReactNativePersistence` in `firebase@10.1.0`?

Comment: What build tool are you using? Can you add its config file here? It would appear that your tool is importing the wrong version of the SDK (it should [automatically pick up the react-native variant](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/pull/7138) of the SDK).

Comment: Thanks @samthecodingman . I added my `metro.config.js` to the question. However, I'm unsure if the link you provided is relevant to my case. I haven't customized the metro config at all. Should I have to make changes to the default metro config?

Comment: I think this error is related to the type definition. I'm getting the error from the vscode.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
      "@firebase/auth": ["./node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/index.rn.d.ts"]
    }
  },
  "extends": "expo/tsconfig.base"
}
```

Apparently, it is a typescript issue. Add the code above to your tsconfig.json file. This fix worked for me.

Comment: Thank you! Is this mentioned in any github issue or any discussion?

Comment: Perfect this works for 10.7.1 when working with Typescsript

Comment: @Yemisrach Yes it was. But I can't seem to find the issue thread

Comment: Found it https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/7584#issuecomment-1692195713

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem. Temporary solution is to use forced type conversion.

```
import * as firebaseAuth from 'firebase/auth';
        
    const reactNativePersistence = (firebaseAuth as any).getReactNativePersistence;
        
            // initialize auth
      export const auth = initializeAuth(app, {
          persistence: reactNativePersistence(AsyncStorage),
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

My solution was to copy the getReactNativePersistence implementation from here: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/master/packages/auth/src/platform_react_native/persistence/react_native.ts, and the common types from here https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/master/packages/auth/src/core/persistence/index.ts
into an internal file in the project, and then replacing the getReactNativePersistence references with my own local version.

The code is simple enough that I didn't see a problem maintaining it myself.

Comment: Worked for me. No idea why we have to do this though

Answer (score 2):

You can create a global Firebase type (firebase.d.ts) file and declare the types like so

```
import { Persistence, ReactNativeAsyncStorage } from "firebase/auth";

declare module "firebase/auth" {
  export declare function getReactNativePersistence(
    storage: ReactNativeAsyncStorage,
  ): Persistence;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand [`facebook/metro#807`](https://github.com/facebook/metro/issues/807) correctly (as mentioned in [`firebase/firebase-js-sd#7138`](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/pull/7138)), you need to update your Metro config to the following:

```
// metro.config.js
const { getDefaultConfig } = require('expo/metro-config');

// initialize configuration
const config = getDefaultConfig(__dirname);
config.resolver.resolverMainFields = ['react-native', 'browser', 'main'];

module.exports = config;
```

Answer (score -1):

Using 10.1.0, this is how I have my current set up:

```
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export const auth = getAuth(app);

setPersistence(auth, { type: "LOCAL" });
```

It throws warnings and errors but it's working