# Module '"firebase/auth"' has no exported member 'getReactNativePersistence'

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

This warning below and instruction is literally coming from firebase yet there is no export to be found and all I am trying to do is sign in with google and its throwing LOG  [TypeError: 0, _auth.signInWithPopup is not a function (it is undefined)]

What am i doing wrong?

:
the warning

Android Bundling complete 150ms
WARN  [2023-12-01T22:05:14.384Z]  @firebase/auth: Auth (10.7.0):

You are initializing Firebase Auth for React Native without providing
AsyncStorage. Auth state will default to memory persistence and will not
persist between sessions. In order to persist auth state,

install the package
"@react-native-async-storage/async-storage" and provide it to
initializeAuth:

```
import { initializeAuth, getReactNativePersistence } from 'firebase/auth';

import ReactNativeAsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
const auth = initializeAuth(app, {
  persistence: getReactNativePersistence(ReactNativeAsyncStorage)
});

    import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';

import { initializeAuth, getReactNativePersistence } from 'firebase/auth';
import { getAuth, GoogleAuthProvider,} from 'firebase/auth';
// import {getReactNativePersistence} from 'firebase/auth/react-native';
import ReactNativeAsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

// TODO: Replace the following with your app's Firebase project configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
  ...
  };
  
export const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const auth = initializeAuth(app, {
    persistence: getReactNativePersistence(ReactNativeAsyncStorage)
  });

export const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
```

packageJson

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.5.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.5.0",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.2.0",
    "@fortawesome/react-native-fontawesome": "^0.3.0",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.21.0",
    "@react-native-masked-view/masked-view": "0.2.9",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "^2.6.1",
    "@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs": "^6.2.19",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.9",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.20",
    "axios": "^1.6.2",
    "expo": "~49.0.15",
    "expo-av": "^13.6.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.6.0",
    "firebase": "^10.7.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.6",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.14.0",
    "react-native-paper": "^5.11.3",
    "react-native-picker-select": "^9.0.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.7.4",
    "react-native-select-dropdown": "^3.4.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^14.0.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^10.0.2",
    "react-navigation": "^5.0.0",
    "react-navigation-header-buttons": "^11.1.1",
    "react-redux": "^8.1.3",
    "redux": "^4.2.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.4.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@types/react": "~18.2.14",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.72.7",
    "react-native-dotenv": "^3.4.9",
    "typescript": "^5.1.3"
  },
  "private": true
```

Comment: Seems this post is nearly identical to yours, and has a few solutions listed?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76914913/cannot-import-getreactnativepersistence-in-firebase10-1-0